# Ticket for Paris Saint-Germain vs. Lyon soccer match: Official second-hand resale not started yet?

Tags: tickets, bookings, paris, events, sports-events

I will be visiting Paris on the day of the PSG - Lyon soccer match on Sep 19. I would like to attend the match, but currently only tickets for the next match of PSG vs. Clermont are officially on sale second-hand at the PSG Ticketplace https://billetterie.psg.fr/en/. Is it because the later matches are too far away in the future? Or does it mean that I won't get a chance to buy second-hand tickets for PSG - Lyon via the Ticketplace anymore? A quick search doesn't seem to turn up relevant information.

If there is still a chance, when should I visit the website again to find out if second-hand tickets are on sale?

Alternatively, it seems that I might be able to register for a MyParis membership and buy the combination tickets Lyon + Montpelier or Lyon + Angers https://billetterie.psg.fr/fr/offres/4c32b705-d8b6-11eb-89cc-0050569ec809/paris-lyon. I wonder if I would then be able to resell the other ticket later via the official platform, since I would have already finished my trip by then.

Comment: This is a site for travel questions. It's difficult to see how ticket availability for a football match fits into that brief.

Comment: @GaspodetheIndomitable I think questions about buying tickets to an event as a tourist are on topic here. See [old meta discussion](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119/is-a-question-about-sport-events-visiting-on-or-off-topic)

Comment: @RedBaron This is not a question about how or where to buy a ticket as a tourist, or even how to get to the stadium. It's specifically about ticket availability.

Comment: @GaspodetheIndomitable Not sure what the difference between "how to buy" and "availability" is according to your criteria. The ticket system seems quite confusing and as described in the question I'm not sure what would be the way to get a ticket, if still possible.

Comment: The title of your question and the whole of the first two paragraphs are about whether a certain class of soccer ticket is on sale. Half of your third paragraph is about reselling an unwanted soccer ticket. None of this is travel-related in any way. If I asked a similar question about my local team, would that be a travel question?

Comment: @GaspodetheIndomitable If somebody is coming to London to see a particular London team play and is confused about the process of getting a ticket, while the locals might have experience & insight and are able to help out. I don't see why it's not or how it's different from other travel questions.

Answer (score 2):

So I got a ticket via the Ticketplace today. I'll summarize what I got out of this if somebody else wants to do the same thing in the future:

- The official PSG Ticketplace for a match seems to open 3 weeks before the match starts, at which point registered users who previously bought tickets can start reselling them.
- A registered user should be able to resell any ticket they get. So the ticket for the later match out of the combo can also be resold. However, I didn't go that route, since I had to register as a member, and since I was not sure of the quality of the seat of the remaining combo tickets. As of today (Aug 31) all combo tickets were also gone.